# Como ajustar altura da imagem bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

http://www.adota-me.tk/anuncio.php?id_anuncio=1455188994

Em modo mobile a altura da imagem está demasiado comprida como posso ajustar essa altura ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi desta forma

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
    #imagem 
    { 
        height: 500px;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Em seu `CSS` você possui a seguinte classe:

```
 <style>
    #imagem
    {
    height: 500px;
    }
</style>
```

Adicione ela em um `media querie` em seu `CSS` com o `height` correto que a imagem ficará da forma que deseja.

Comment: Esse style na pratica já não esta fazendo nada eu tirei ele agora e se verificar ele nao faz qualquer efeito

Comment: Se você inspecionar os elementos HTML (F12) e remover a classe verá que ele faz algo sim!